# Tracking UTM paramaters in iframe with own Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm having issues with tracking the UTM parameters in Google Analytics on an iframe.

My website is embedded in an iframe on http://www.blokker.be/inuwkot and http://www.blokker.be/danstonkot. The visitors go straight to the two links (either dutch or french). No visitors go straight to my own domain.

In the overview page form analytics I can view the amount of visitors/views but not the UTM parameters. I can only see it's a referal.

Any ideas on how to get the UTM url's working in the iframe so I can see where my visitors come from?

Answer (score 0):

Since your frame content is located on a different domain you can not track url parameters from the hosting page without support from the domain owners - they would either have to append the parameters to the frame url, or send a message using the [postMessage interface](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=postmessage%20to%20iframe) which allows cross-domain communication between pages and embedded frames.

So the page has to send the information to the frame, you cannot simply access it (for security reasons). If the owners of the blokker.be domain do not support that then you are out of luck.